# Selenium-Webdriver using unwanted driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I started using selenium webdriver and it was working one day and not the next without changing any code or any versions.  I am running it through firefox, and it opens a small firefox window and then closes almost instantaneously.

The error says "chrome" and I can't figure it out. If you look about 7 lines down, it says "[remote server] chrome".  No idea where the "chrome" is coming from. Here is my error message:

```
Loaded suite test/create_auction
Started
E
===============================================================================
Error: test_create_auction(CreateAuction)
  Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: gBrowser is not defined
[remote server] chrome://browser/content/browser.js:15811:in `getBrowser'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/session.js:3296:in `wdSession.prototype.setChromeWindow'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10975:in `nsCommandProcessor.prototype.newSession'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10866:in `nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7691:in `Dispatcher.executeAs/<'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7837:in `Resource.prototype.handle'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7784:in `Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:10693:in `WebDriverServer/<.handle'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1935:in `createHandlerFunc/<'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2261:in `ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1168:in `Connection.prototype.process'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1616:in `RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1464:in `RequestReader.prototype._processBody'
[remote server] file:///var/folders/_w/_81xdz4n1x5_9kd3xxtqlv3w0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140218-6483-158snzk/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1333:in `RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady'

test/create_auction.rb:9:in `setup'
===============================================================================
E
===============================================================================
Error: test_create_auction(CreateAuction)
  NoMethodError: undefined method `quit' for nil:NilClass
test/create_auction.rb:17:in `teardown'
===============================================================================


Finished in 7.42258 seconds.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

0.13 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s
```

And here is my test file:

```
require "json"
require "selenium-webdriver"
gem "test-unit"
require "test/unit"

class CreateAuction < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://localhost:3000/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end

  def test_create_auction
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Sign Up Now!").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Select Silver Plus").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisbuyer@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_first_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_first_name").send_keys "Buyer"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_last_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_last_name").send_keys "Mercaris"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password_confirmation").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password_confirmation").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "organization_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "organization_name").send_keys "Buyer"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "newsletter").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "required").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "payment_submit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Select Crops").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "commodity_ids_").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//input[@id='commodity_ids_'])[2]").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//input[@id='commodity_ids_'])[3]").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    organization_id_buyer = @driver.current_url.split("/").last
    # added class "primary" because it couldn't locate by ID
    @driver.find_element(:class, "primary").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "register_for_auctions").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "elevator").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_application_physically_owns_commodities").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_application_is_member_of_ngfa").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisseller@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys ""
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Sign Up Now!").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Select Silver Plus").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisseller@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_first_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_first_name").send_keys "Seller"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_last_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_last_name").send_keys "Mercaris"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password_confirmation").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password_confirmation").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "organization_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "organization_name").send_keys "Seller"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "newsletter").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "required").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "payment_submit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Select Crops").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "commodity_ids_").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//input[@id='commodity_ids_'])[2]").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//input[@id='commodity_ids_'])[3]").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    organization_id_seller = @driver.current_url.split("/").last
    @driver.find_element(:class, "primary").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "register_for_auctions").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "grower").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_application_physically_owns_commodities").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_application_is_member_of_ngfa").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "websitetest@mercariscompany.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "password"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Organizations").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Buyer").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "review_and_approve").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Organizations").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Seller").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "review_and_approve").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Organizations").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Buyer").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[3]/a/div/h4").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Approve").click
    @driver.find_element(:css, "a.btn.btn-primary > span.translation_missing").click
    Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "auction_organization_id")).select_by(:text, "Buyer")
    tomorrow = (Date.today + 1).to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %R")
    yesterday = (Date.today - 1).to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %R")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_start_time").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_start_time").send_keys "#{yesterday}"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_end_time").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_end_time").send_keys "#{tomorrow}"
    Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "auction_auction_type")).select_by(:text, "reverse")
    Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "auction_contract_id")).select_by(:text, "2013 Organic Corn (feed)")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_quantity").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_quantity").send_keys "5000"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_lot_size").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_lot_size").send_keys "1000"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_location_attributes_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_location_attributes_name").send_keys "Buyer Elevator"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_location_attributes_state").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_location_attributes_state").send_keys "Illinois"
    delivery_start = (Date.today + 30).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    delivery_end = (Date.today + 32).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_delivery_begin_date").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_delivery_begin_date").send_keys "#{delivery_start}"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_delivery_end_date").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_delivery_end_date").send_keys "#{delivery_end}"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_delivery_methods").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_delivery_methods").send_keys "Truck"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_conveyance_costs").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_conveyance_costs").send_keys "Buyer"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_reserve_price").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_reserve_price").send_keys "500"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    auction_id = @driver.current_url.split("/").last
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisbuyer@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "websitetest@mercariscompany.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "password"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Organizations").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Seller").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[3]/a/div/h4").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Approve").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisseller@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "view auction").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "offer_lots").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "offer_lots").send_keys "4"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "offer_price").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "offer_price").send_keys "5.00"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "offer_accept_terms").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "websitetest@mercariscompany.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "password"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auctions_index").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "view_#{auction_id}").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "new_invoice_button").click
    Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "auction_invoice_buyer_id")).select_by(:text, "Buyer")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_invoice_amount").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_invoice_amount").send_keys "19,800.00"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_invoice_fee").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_invoice_fee").send_keys "198.00"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisbuyer@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "pay invoice").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Verify Your Bank Account").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "name").send_keys "Buyer"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "routing_number").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "routing_number").send_keys "021000021"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "account_number").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "account_number").send_keys "9900000000"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Back To Dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "pay invoice").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Verify Your Bank Account").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "bank[amount1]").clear
    @driver.find_element(:name, "bank[amount1]").send_keys "1"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "bank[amount2]").clear
    @driver.find_element(:name, "bank[amount2]").send_keys "1"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Approve Invoice").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "approve_invoice").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "invoice receipt").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    # Creating the Transfer
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "websitetest@mercariscompany.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "password"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auctions_index").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "view_#{auction_id}").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "new_transfer_button").click
    Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "auction_transfer_seller_id")).select_by(:text, "Seller")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_transfer_amount").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_transfer_amount").send_keys "19,602.0"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_transfer_fee").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auction_transfer_fee").send_keys "198.0"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "mercarisseller@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "organic123"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "accept transfer").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Verify Your Bank Account").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "name").send_keys "Seller Account"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "routing_number").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "routing_number").send_keys "021000021"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "account_number").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "account_number").send_keys "9900000000"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Back To Dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "accept transfer").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "approve_transfer").click
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Back to Dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "transfer receipt").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Back to Dashboard").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
    # destroy auction and orgs
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_email").send_keys "websitetest@mercariscompany.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "user_password").send_keys "password"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "auctions_index").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "view_#{auction_id}").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "invoice_destroy").click
    @driver.switch_to().alert().accept
    @driver.find_element(:link, "< Back to Auction").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "transfer_destroy").click
    @driver.switch_to().alert().accept
    @driver.find_element(:id, "destroy_auction").click
    @driver.switch_to().alert().accept
    @driver.find_element(:id, "admin").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Organizations").click
    @driver.find_element(:id, "organization_destroy_#{organization_id_seller}").click
    @driver.switch_to().alert().accept
    @driver.find_element(:id, "organization_destroy_#{organization_id_buyer}").click
    @driver.switch_to().alert().accept
    @driver.find_element(:id, "logout").click
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def alert_present?()
    @driver.switch_to.alert
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end

  def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
    alert = @driver.switch_to().alert()
    alert_text = alert.text
    if (@accept_next_alert) then
      alert.accept()
    else
      alert.dismiss()
    end
    alert_text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end

end
```

I have tried changing the "quit" message, etc.

Comment: @user1177636 Thanks, I will try this ASAP. :) Although... Surely selenium would work with a new -v of firefox.

Comment: No, you got me wrong. I mean try avoid auto upgrade Firefox. If you had it upgraded, please downgrade to 26 or lower. Selenium will only work with the version it supports to, not usually the latest.

Comment: The `chrome://` protocol is a red herring: [it has nothing to do with Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/517160/why-does-firefox-use-the-chrome-protocol-schema-in-urls), and is just an internal protocol used by Firefox. I'm no expert at reading Ruby stack traces, but both of those errors seem to boil down to "the browser reference is null".

Comment: @rutter Hmm, interesting.  Thanks for the info.  Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Would be nice if Selenium gave more diagnostics. Like @user1177636 suggested, you might try downgrading to a previous Firefox version. The interaction between Selenium Server and Firefox tends to be a moving target between versions, unfortunately.